# VB.Net Downgrading the needed .net framework

Tags: vb.net

I dont think you can do this, but just in case, I can but ask...

I write programs in VB 2010 which uses .Net Framework 4.0. However my school currently only has .Net Framework 3.1 (3.something, think its 1)

Is there anyway i can "downgrade" the needed .net framework, or even just select another .net version to use?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your project file, just target .NET 3.5 instead of 4.0.  Properties -> Application -> TargetFramework.

However, if you have used specific .NET 4 features these will obviously not work so you might have to make other changes.

UPDATE:  Sorry about missing the VB.NET

Got Project Properties ->Compile -> Advanced Compile Options and it is on the bottom of the dialog.

Comment: I noticed that in C#, but couldn't find it in VB (I looked when I saw you could do it in C#) Ill look again when I have the chance, but is there any reason why it might not be there?

Comment: Ah ok, thanks! I did think it was odd that the option was in C# but not VB, and this explains it! Thanks